# How to plot a pie plot inside a donut plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, pie-chart, donut-chart

The data in csv format:

```
,H,E,C
A,8393.0,2872.0,5649.0
R,4360.0,2188.0,3892.0
N,2029.0,1137.0,4714.0
D,3234.0,1436.0,6761.0
C,754.0,743.0,1185.0
Q,3529.0,1278.0,2844.0
E,6649.0,2053.0,5248.0
G,2338.0,2200.0,10054.0
H,1389.0,1006.0,2112.0
I,4348.0,4210.0,2734.0
L,8642.0,4386.0,5590.0
K,4805.0,2194.0,4895.0
M,1884.0,913.0,1459.0
F,2767.0,2377.0,2601.0
P,1397.0,987.0,6678.0
S,3136.0,2226.0,6094.0
T,2986.0,2884.0,4950.0
W,987.0,787.0,930.0
Y,2218.0,2145.0,2205.0
V,4689.0,5950.0,3699.0
```

So here's how I can plot a pie chart for visualizing the percentage of H, E and C

```
ss_dist_df=pd.read_csv("counts", index_col=0)

plt.pie(ss_dist_df.sum(),  autopct='%1.1f%%', startangle=90)
```

However, how can I plot another external ring with the aminoacid distribution (the 20 aminoacids) at each conformation (H, E or C)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could adapt the example code of [matplotlib's pie chart example](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_and_donut_labels.html).  For the values in the donut, you can concatenate all column values (reversed to have 'A' at the left) and use three times the dataframe's index (also reversed).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data_str = ''',H,E,C
A,8393.0,2872.0,5649.0
R,4360.0,2188.0,3892.0
N,2029.0,1137.0,4714.0
D,3234.0,1436.0,6761.0
C,754.0,743.0,1185.0
Q,3529.0,1278.0,2844.0
E,6649.0,2053.0,5248.0
G,2338.0,2200.0,10054.0
H,1389.0,1006.0,2112.0
I,4348.0,4210.0,2734.0
L,8642.0,4386.0,5590.0
K,4805.0,2194.0,4895.0
M,1884.0,913.0,1459.0
F,2767.0,2377.0,2601.0
P,1397.0,987.0,6678.0
S,3136.0,2226.0,6094.0
T,2986.0,2884.0,4950.0
W,987.0,787.0,930.0
Y,2218.0,2145.0,2205.0
V,4689.0,5950.0,3699.0'''
ss_dist_df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data_str), index_col=0)
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
plt.pie(ss_dist_df.sum(), labels=ss_dist_df.columns, labeldistance=0.5, textprops={'size': 16},
        radius=0.7, startangle=0, colors=['skyblue', 'salmon', 'lightgreen'])
plt.pie(list(ss_dist_df['H'][::-1]) + list(ss_dist_df['E'][::-1]) + list(ss_dist_df['C'][::-1]),
        labels=3 * list(ss_dist_df.index[::-1]),
        colors=plt.cm.tab20.colors,
        labeldistance=0.9, textprops={'size': 8},
        wedgeprops=dict(width=0.28), startangle=0)
plt.show()
```

[image: pie chart surrounded by donut chart]